# Symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 "_swift_stdlib_isstackallocationsafe" - XCode Ract Native 0.64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, ipa

I'm trying to Archive my react native(version 0.64.2) project on a Mac Intel, but keep getting the below error:

````
  "_swift_stdlib_isStackAllocationSafe", referenced from:
      _$ss10_NativeSetV6filteryAByxGSbxKXEKFSo8NSObjectC_Tg50126$s9RemoteINR10BLEManagerC14centralManager_23didDisconnectPeripheral5errorySo09CBCentralE0C_So12CBPeripheralCs5Error_pSgtFSbSo8D6CXEfU_Tf1cn_n in BLEManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)```
````